# How do I submit one form multiple times with different values?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

**BACKGROUND**
I'm very new to using Scrapy and webscraping in general, and I'm attempting to access a target webpage, fill the form present there, submit that form and scrape data from the page that has been returned into items.  After completing those steps, I want to then go back to the target webpage, fill the form with different information, scrape the **new** data that has been returned, and append this data to those same items.

**WHAT I HAVE**
The following code fills out the target form, scrapes the returned page for info, and places that info into items.

```
import scrapy
from AirScraper.items import AirscraperItem

class airSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "airSpider"
    start_urls = ["https://book.jetblue.com"]
    origin = "MCO"
    dest = "BOS"
    dateDep = "2015-05-13"
    dateRet = "2015-05-15"

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formname = "searchForm",
            formdata={'origin' : self.origin, 'destination' : self.dest, 'departureDate' : self.dateDep, 'returnDate' : self.dateRet},
            callback=self.after_search
        )

    def after_search(self, response):
        flights = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "flight-row no-mint")]')
        for sel in flights:
            #scrape data about target flight
            yield item
```

**WHAT I NEED**
Once I've scraped data from the first form request, I need to then return to the original form page, fill it out with similar data, and then scrape its results as well.  I'm just unsure how to go about telling the spider to return to that first page and perform a different set of actions.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out,  this is actually really simple.
In the parse method, simply replace the single return with the following code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formname = "searchForm",
        formdata={'origin' : self.origin, 'destination' : self.dest, 'departureDate' : self.dateDep, 'returnDate' : self.dateRet},
        callback=self.after_search
    )

    yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formname = "searchForm",
        formdata={'origin' : self.NEWorigin, 'destination' : self.NEWdest, 'departureDate' : self.NEWdateDep, 'returnDate' : self.NEWdateRet},
        callback=self.after_search_2
    )
```

This will make the spider that you've defined perform both the first and second searches, with whatever new information you've defined.